# What does it mean by the associated metric of a norm?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

This is a homework question[image: HW question]

Here I don't understand what does it mean by *the associated metric of a norm*. Can anyone clarify this term for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To say $d$ is the associated metric of a norm $\| \cdot \|$ on $X$ if
$$\|x - y\| = d(x, y) \tag{1}$$
for all $x, y \in X$. A norm can always produce a metric in this way. The question is about a sufficient condition to go the reverse direction: when can we start with a metric $d$, and construct a norm $\| \cdot \|$ so that $(1)$ holds?

Comment: Thanks!! It says if and only if though, it should be both directions I suppose?

Comment: Oh right, yes, it is both directions!

Comment: Actually I stuck on the reverse direction, that is, if $d$ is a metric satisfying those two conditions (translation invariance and positive homogeneity), I want to show $d(x,y) = ||x-y||$. I tried to prove that first $d$ is a norm, but it seemed not to be the right direction to work with. Can you give a hint?

Comment: Hint: $d$ is not a norm, as $d$ accepts two vectors, whereas a norm only accepts one. Try showing $\|x\| := d(x, 0)$ is a norm.

Comment: Oh, that makes more sense. Thanks a lot!!